# How to remove html tags

Tags: vue.js, datatable, ckeditor

Hi everyone I want to not show "html tags" When i have data in tables, but i want show text only like microsoft word, I'm not sure on the support, I don't know to fix it and I have tried many times, I think can't to remove all the html tags from string, I used CKeditor to input and datatable of vue output from vueX

help me please

[Example Outpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehajP.png)

```js
<template>
  <div class="container" id="annoucements">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">
            <div class="card-icon">
              <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
            </div>
            <h4 class="card-title">
              {{ $t('global.table') }}
              <strong>{{ $t('cruds.annoucement.title') }}</strong>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-overlay" v-show="loading">
                  <div class="table-overlay-container">
                    <material-spinner></material-spinner>
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <datatable
                  :columns="columns"
                  :data="data"
                  :total="total"
                  :query="query"
                  :xprops="xprops"
                  :HeaderSettings="false"
                  :pageSizeOptions="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
                >
                  <global-search :query="query" class="pull-left" />
                  <span style="margin-left:10%">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-default"
                      @click="fetchIndexData"
                      :disabled="loading"
                      :class="{ disabled: loading }"
                      >
                      <i class="material-icons" :class="{ 'fa-spin': loading }">
                      refresh
                      </i>
                      {{ $t('global.refresh') }}
                    </button>
                  </span>
                  <header-settings :columns="columns" class="pull-right" />
                </datatable>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import TranslatedHeader from '@components/Datatables/TranslatedHeader'
import HeaderSettings from '@components/Datatables/HeaderSettings'
import GlobalSearch from '@components/Datatables/GlobalSearch'
import DatatableAttachments from '@components/Datatables/DatatableAttachments'

export default {
  components: {
    GlobalSearch,
    HeaderSettings
  },
  data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.id',
          field: 'id',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          sortable: true,
          colStyle: 'width: 100px;'
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.annoucement',
          field: 'annoucement',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          tdComp: DatatableAttachments
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.name',
          field: 'name',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.number',
          field: 'number',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.short_name',
          field: 'short_name',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.allow_date',
          field: 'allow_date',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          title: 'cruds.annoucement.fields.description',
          field: 'description',
          thComp: TranslatedHeader,
        }
      ],
      query: { sort: 'id', order: 'desc', limit: 100, s: '' },
      xprops: {
        module: 'AnnoucementsIndex',
        route: 'annoucements',
        permission_prefix: 'annoucement_'
      }
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.resetState()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('AnnoucementsIndex', ['data', 'total', 'loading'])
  },
  watch: {
    query: {
      handler(query) {
        this.setQuery(query)
        this.fetchIndexData()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('AnnoucementsIndex', [
      'fetchIndexData',
      'setQuery',
      'resetState'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use method below for each cell or make an copy of data that contains string without html:

```js
removeHtmlTags(htmlString) {
    const tmp = document.createElement('DIV');
    tmp.innerHTML = htmlString;
    return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || '';
}
```